# How to access JSON array of Java class in AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, java, json, angularjs

I have list of DTOs(POJO) data in my java code. I am converting that data list to JSON array. I want to initialize my `$scope.data variable` of AngularJS controller with that data to show in UI.

My java code in ProjectBean class

```
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int iterator = 0; iterator < dbProjectListSize; iterator++) {
        JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();            
        responseDetailsJson.put("name", tempChartProject.getText());
        responseDetailsJson.put("color", "#9FC5F8");
        responseDetailsJson.put("from", ChartProject.getStart_date());                                      
        jsonArray.add(responseDetailsJson);
        }
```

AngularJS Controller

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.data =projectBean.jsonArray;
}]);
```

I want to initialize the `$scope.data` variable with the Json list from the Project bean class, to display this data in UI.

please help me.

Comment: Hi, where do you save the data in the client side? I don't see in your java method a `response.write` for the jsonArray.  you need to create an angular service and expose a method to call this POJO to retrieve the jsonArray.

Comment: @ Saar I am working on JSF and new to AngularJS.  Can you provide any code snippet as answer for this question ?

Comment: @SubhakarPatnala - you need to make httprequest and assign the response to your scope variable

Answer (score 0):

Use service with controller and Make sure you inject service .

in controller.js

```
controllersModule.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http,  **FactoryYouwant**) 
    {

        **FactoryYouwant**.getdata().then (function(responseData){  
            $scope.ResponseFromServer =responseData;
    }
```

in service.js

```
controllersModule.factory('**FactoryYouwant**, function($http) {
    var responseData = null;

    return {
        getdata : function(){           
            responseData = "$http.post "; //that gets you data;
            return responseData;
        }

      };
});
```

I hope this helps.